# Question regarding Drake's current inverse kinematics code

Tags: drake

I've been looking into some papers on inverse kinematics planning with collision avoidance for a robotic arm. I found this paper called, "Global Inverse Kinematics via Mixed-Integer Convex Optimization", which I believe a few of Drake's developer's names are on.

On this paper, it says that the code is already part of drake. However, when I found it, the code was placed in attic. (https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/attic/multibody/global_inverse_kinematics.h)

In the current kuka arm example under move_iiwa_ee, the IK code called ConstraintRelaxingIk is used instead.

1. I would like to know why the "Global Inverse Kinematics via Mixed-Integer Convex Optimization" IK code was put to the side and if there were any problems with it.
2. Also, I'm not sure if the current ConstraintRelaxingIk does collision avoidance. Could someone clarify this?

(And if it does, are there any extra steps to take other than inserting an obstacle model?)

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your interest in our work.

The global inverse kinematics code is in `attic` folder because it uses `RigidBodyTree`, which will be deprecated soon. <strike>I haven't got time to rewrite the code to use the new MultibodyTree yet. For the moment, if you would like to try the approach in the global IK paper, could you use the code in the `attic` folder? I will try to move the code out of `attic` folder to use `MultibodyTree`</strike>. (**Update** The code is already moved out of `attic` folder. Now it is in `inverse_kinematics` [folder](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/inverse_kinematics/global_inverse_kinematics.h))

ConstraintRelaxingIk doesn't handle collision avoidance. On the other hand, you can use [InverseKinematics](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/ab20bf25d9e9c05f861d7b6905cd6ef4dd9950c7/multibody/inverse_kinematics/inverse_kinematics.h) class. It formulates IK as a nonlinear optimization problem, and calls the nonlinear solver to find the solution. Specifically for collision avoidance, you could use [AddMinimumDistanceConstraint](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/ab20bf25d9e9c05f861d7b6905cd6ef4dd9950c7/multibody/inverse_kinematics/inverse_kinematics.h#L201-L223) to impose a minimal distance constraint between **all** pairs of geometries. Alternatively, you could call [AddDistanceConstraint](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/ab20bf25d9e9c05f861d7b6905cd6ef4dd9950c7/multibody/inverse_kinematics/inverse_kinematics.h#L225-L237) if you want to impose a distance constraint between a specific pair of geometries. I would actually recommend trying `InverseKinematics` class first before you try the global IK approach, since `InverseKinematics` uses `MultibodyPlant`, and usually runs faster than the global approach.

BTW, the formulation used in `InverseKinematics` class is described in section II.B and II.C of this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hongkai_Dai/publication/281374074_Whole-body_Motion_Planning_with_Centroidal_Dynamics_and_Full_Kinematics/links/55e455bb08aede0b57345a9e/Whole-body-Motion-Planning-with-Centroidal-Dynamics-and-Full-Kinematics.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I’ll be taking a look.

Comment: Sorry for the belated reply. The global inverse kinematics code has been rewritten to use the current MultibodyPlant. https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/inverse_kinematics/global_inverse_kinematics.h